# ThinkingSphinx: Viewing Result Weights when using BatchedSearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

On ThiningSphinx v3 how do I retrieve search result weights in combination with BatchedSearch?

Im using a BatchedSearch as described [here](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/upgrading.html):

```
batch = ThinkingSphinx::BatchedSearch.new
batch.searches << Article.search('foo', :select => '*, weight()')
batch.searches << Article.search(:conditions => {:name => 'bar'}, :select => '*, weight()')
batch.searches << Article.search_for_ids('baz', :select => '*, weight()')
batch.populate
res = batch.searches #=> [[foo results], [bar results], [baz results]]
```

In each of these 3 search result sets, i want to access the [Result Weights](http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html#weights) but it seems that the weights can only be accessed through a single search object? After the above code block, i have tried:

```
res.each do |w|
 w.context[:panes] << ThinkingSphinx::Panes::WeightPane
end

res.first.first #is a valid search result

res.first.first.weight
#returns error: 
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `weight' for #<Work:0xb2a9a648>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the pane to each search object *before* you populate the results. So, try the following instead:

```
batch = ThinkingSphinx::BatchedSearch.new
batch.searches << Article.search('foo', :select => '*, weight()')
batch.searches << Article.search(:conditions => {:name => 'bar'}, :select => '*, weight()')
batch.searches << Article.search_for_ids('baz', :select => '*, weight()')
batch.searches.each do |search|
  search.context[:panes] << ThinkingSphinx::Panes::WeightPane
end
batch.populate

res = batch.searches
res.first.first.weight
```

Comment: After making change you suggested, i no longer get "undefined method", however weight is returning nil for all search results. Is there any other config required to retrieve weight? Btw thanks for your help and great plugin.

Comment: My bad, i didnt include the additional search paramater to retrieve weight(): :select => '*, weight()'. I'll update my original question to include these so its clear. Thanks again.